# Retrieve YouTube channel with custom username

Tags: youtube-data-api

I can easily get what I want for channels that have a YouTube username but sometimes they don't have a username so I have to use the Channel ID. People can also have a custom username http://www.youtube.com/c/customusername but I can't for the life of me work out how to retrieve a channel just by passing the custom username.

Comment: Try to explore the settings of youtube i know u can customize or create ur own youtube channel link

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve using the youtube-api, not modify my own channel

Comment: Having same issue so annoying that username is or can be different from channel name and is or can be different again from channel title. The dirty work around that is not 100% is to use the search api enter username into the q parameter and snippet into the field option. If you set max results 1 that should (sadly not always) return the user you are after

Comment: Yes, I discovered your solution but it just felt too hacky to use in production.

Comment: Also, with that method, because I consult the statistics fields I would now have to do 2 requests, one to get the channel ID and another to get the statistics.